# python - How to inspect code of function created with exec

Tags: python, function

I have a function that was created with `exec()` inside another function and passed as an argument to the main program. How can I get the code of said function?
I tried `inspec.getsourcelines()` and `inspec.getsource()` but I get the following error

```
IOError: could not get source code
```

Is there a way around this?

MWE
main file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from ext import makeF
import inspect

f=makeF()
f()
inspect.getsource(f)
```

then external file:

```
def makeF():
    script="def sayA():\n\tprint('Aah')"
    exec(script)
    return sayA
```

Comment: Can you add your code on question to make it more clear!

Comment: The actual code is way too long. I'll make a mwe in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 3 the solution is the `__globals__` attribute of the functions.

With your example :

```
>>> f.__globals__['txt']
"def sayA():\n\tprint('Aah')"
```

Unfortunately I could not find anything like for Python 2.

---

The reason why the other methods cannot work, is because they use the filename of the module and here you do not have any file.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. I've been digging around and came to the same conclusion as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12072941/660848).

I don't know your code, but I think in your specific case you could return a custom object containing the source code of the function (which you seem to have - you're passing it to exec) together with the actual compiled function. You could even leverage Python's `__call__` magic method to better emulate the original behaviour. Here's a sample:

```py
class FunctionWithCode:
    def __init__(self, source, func_name):
        exec(source)
        self.source = source
        self.func = locals()[func_name]

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.func(*args, **kwargs)

f = FunctionWithCode("def sayA():\n\tprint('Aah')", 'sayA')

f()
```

which prints Aah as expected. You would need to know the function name when creating the object but this is the same for your sample code.

Comment: I had kind of solved it by replacing `return sayA` with `return sayA, script`, and that way I just had it as a variable. I just figured there was something I was missing with `inspect`. Your workaround is pretty good though. I think it could be easily wrapped so the name would be retrieved by a simple parsing of the first line of code.